# I need laravel to return all object attributes upon saving including null attributes

Tags: json, laravel, null, save, return

I have a model instance for which I set the attributes from a post request using `$my_instance->fill($request_json)` and after saving using `$my_instance->save()` the instance as a record in the database, I want to receive the saved object back with all its attributes using `return response()->json($my_instance)`. Now this works fine as long as I provide all the attributes I set in the `protected $fillable = []` on the model class inside the post request body. But when I want to send only part of the attributes in the post request, what happens is that inside tinker I see the skipped attributes are set to null. This is fine. But the problem is when I return using `return response()->json($my_instance)` I don't see the skipped attributes and I want them to be returned even with them being null in my databse. Is there a way to instruct laravel to do so?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A possible implementation to your question **COULD** be to:

- Allow all possible fields that are getting nulled out to be fillable in your model.
- Then, use a middleware with collections to do:

  ```
  $form_stuff = $request->all();
  $form_stuff = collect($form_stuff);
  $things_you_want = $form_stuff->only('wanted_field_1','wanted_field_2');

  $things_that_should_be_null = $form_stuff->only('nulled_field_1','nulled_field_2');

  $keys = array_keys($thins_that_should_be_null);

  $values = array_fill(0, count($keys), null);
  $new_array_of_nulled_things = array_combine($keys, $values);

  var_dump($things_you_want);

  var_dump($new_array_of_nulled_things);

  die();
  ```

**WARNING: Since there was no code posted, this is just concept mostly and has not been tested so you will have to play with it to get it work the way you want.**